# SQL in php force WHERE IN to find more than one time the same id

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to to do a cart where the products have customizations... To avoid lot of queries in the data base I have tried to save the results in an array after the query. The query looks like this:

```
$sql = 'SELECT * 
            FROM cc_restaurants_menu 
            WHERE menu_id 
            IN ("7","50","50") 
            ORDER BY FIELD (menu_id,"7","50","50")';
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if($result->rowCount() > 0) {
    while($row = $result->fetch()) {
        $names[] = $row['menu_product'] .'<br>';
    }
}
```

But the problem with this is that the query avoid the repeated ids. (I need repeated ids because the people can add the product more than one time).

Is there anyway to get the repeated ids more than one time?

The only idea I have is do something like (if the ids are in an array) :

```
foreach($ids as $d) {
  //query here the database based in each id
}
```

thanks in advance

Comment: `SELECT DISTINCT *`?

Comment: no, just tried and is the same, give the 2 results instead of 3

Comment: what is the result if you call the query directly from the database?

Comment: for example if I return the name of the product I get "name1" (id 7) and "name2" (id 50)... only 2 results, not three

Comment: This is unrelated to your question, but why are you repeating the value 50 twice? It's redundant.

Comment: make join with the order table

Comment: @RacilHilan is because this ids are stored in a '$_SESSION' so the customer can add to many times the same item with different customizations

Comment: well if its same id everytime than info generated from database will always be same so its ok to save info single time only in array.... for customization of single item multiple times, use a different array that keeps track of no. of times product added for customiztion and link both arrays....

Comment: Yeah, but you can easily check if a value already exists in the session before you try to add it. Otherwise you may end up with some long redundant values. Anyway, it's not related to the problem in your question. It was just a comment.

Comment: yes that is true @ManojSalvi I should think a way to add quantities if the item is repeated and then split the item with each customization

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Think you might need one query for each menu_id, and use UNION ALL to join the results together.

Something like this:-

```
SELECT * 
FROM cc_restaurants_menu 
WHERE menu_id = "7"
UNION ALL
SELECT * 
FROM cc_restaurants_menu 
WHERE menu_id = "50"
UNION ALL
SELECT * 
FROM cc_restaurants_menu 
WHERE menu_id = "50"
ORDER BY FIELD (menu_id,"7","50","50")
```

Or build up the required menu ids in a sub query which you then join against the main table.

```
SELECT cc_restaurants_menu.* 
FROM cc_restaurants_menu 
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT 7 AS a_menu_id UNION ALL SELECT 50 UNION ALL SELECT 50
) sub0
ON cc_restaurants_menu.menu_id = sub0.a_menu_id
ORDER BY FIELD (cc_restaurants_menu.menu_id,"7","50","50")
```

Generating the first query with implode would be done something like this:-

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM cc_restaurants_menu WHERE menu_id = '".implode("' UNION ALL SELECT * FROM cc_restaurants_menu WHERE menu_id = '", id_array)."' ORDER BY FIELD (menu_id,'".implode("','", id_array)."')";
```

and generating the 2nd query with implode would be done something like this:-

```
$sql = "SELECT cc_restaurants_menu.* FROM cc_restaurants_menu INNER JOIN (SELECT ".implode(" AS a_menu_id UNION ALL SELECT ", id_array) AS a_menu_id ) sub0 ON cc_restaurants_menu.menu_id = sub0.a_menu_id ORDER BY FIELD (cc_restaurants_menu.menu_id,".implode(",", id_array).")";
```

Comment: i think that this will cause problems if you have random id's and random amounts

Comment: Only if the number of ids gets very large. The query can be built up relatively easily in php using implode.

Comment: well give a few minutes that I need to think how the implode will look

Comment: to be honest doesnt looks to elegant but is working so at the moment it the right answer... thanks ... i did the first query, is working well